# Relocate Data Directory without resync

Tags: blockchain, linux, datadir

If I have an exported binary copy of the block chain how can I import it but to a different directory than the default location? For example if I run `geth import /mnt/blockchains/ETH/eth.bak` it will begin importing to the default location if I run `geth --datadir "/mnt/blockchains/ETH/"` it will begin syncing the blockchain from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the directory to the new place and create a symlink to it, and run geth as normal.

Comment: The drive was filed so I exported to a NFS mount than deleted the data in /chaindata

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think no. Maybe I didn't give enough info in the post. Doesn't your answer depend on the original data directory still being present?

Comment: You wanted to move from the default directory to another one, the symlink approach will make you do that. If you already deleted the original chaindata, sure you have to start over.

Comment: Makes sense, I wasn't sure if I was able to import the block chain that I previously exported. I'll just resync. Thanks